Web3ValidationError when calling contract function using web3.py
I am trying to deploy a trading bot and trying to call a contract function called simpleSwap.  here is the function in the abi:
{'inputs': [{'components': [{'internalType': 'uint256',
                                      'name': 'nonceAndMeta',
                                      'type': 'uint256'},
                                     {'internalType': 'uint128',
                                      'name': 'expiry',
                                      'type': 'uint128'},
                                     {'internalType': 'address',
                                      'name': 'makerAsset',
                                      'type': 'address'},
                                     {'internalType': 'address',
                                      'name': 'takerAsset',
                                      'type': 'address'},
                                     {'internalType': 'address',
                                      'name': 'maker',
                                      'type': 'address'},
                                     {'internalType': 'address',
                                      'name': 'taker',
                                      'type': 'address'},
                                     {'internalType': 'uint256',
                                      'name': 'makerAmount',
                                      'type': 'uint256'},
                                     {'internalType': 'uint256',
                                      'name': 'takerAmount',
                                      'type': 'uint256'}],
                      'internalType': 'struct MainnetRFQ.Order',
                      'name': '_order',
                      'type': 'tuple'},
                     {'internalType': 'bytes',
                      'name': '_signature',
                      'type': 'bytes'}],
          'name': 'simpleSwap',
          'outputs': [],
          'stateMutability': 'payable',
          'type': 'function'}

Here is my code to call the function:
def send_order():
    # order_dict is response from the api which is a firm quote from an exchange
    order = order_dict.get('order')
    df = pd.DataFrame([order])
    nonce_and_meta = df.iloc[0, 1].astype(int).item()
    signature = order_dict.get('signature')
    signature_bytes = bytes(signature, 'utf-8')
    sw = [
        [
            eth_abi.encode(['uint256'], [nonce_and_meta]),
            eth_abi.encode(['uint128'], [int(order.get('expiry'))]),
            w3.to_checksum_address(order.get('makerAsset')),
            w3.to_checksum_address(order.get('takerAsset')),
            w3.to_checksum_address(order.get('maker')),
            w3.to_checksum_address(order.get('taker')),
            eth_abi.encode(['uint256'], [int(order.get('makerAmount'))]),
            eth_abi.encode(['uint256'], [int(order.get('takerAmount'))])
        ],
        signature_bytes
        ]

    contract = w3.eth.contract(address=dexalot_main_address, abi=abi.get('abi'))
    simple_swap = contract.functions.simpleSwap(sw) # --> error occurs here

Error:
Could not identify the intended function with name `simpleSwap`, positional arguments with type(s) `((bytes,bytes,address,address,address,address,bytes,bytes),bytes)` and keyword arguments with type(s) `{}`.
Found 1 function(s) with the name `simpleSwap`: ['simpleSwap((uint256,uint128,address,address,address,address,uint256,uint256),bytes)']
Function invocation failed due to improper number of arguments.

I am very new at interacting with smart contracts so please be nice.  I looked all over and couldn't find an answer to my question.  I'm certain I'm just missing something simple and feel like an idiot. I look forward to your replies and thank you for your help.
